# Check for validation errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two tabs in my aspx page, 5 controls in each page, and am having a `single save` button for these two tabs.

All the 10 fields are mandatory, so am using `required field validator` here, suppose the users filling all the fields in the 1st tab and press `save`, nothing will happen, since the required field validator is fired in the 2nd tab.

For this situation, I need to tell them to fill the fields in the 2nd tab.

I've planned to check if any validation errors occured in both the tabs, if yes then I can raise a pop up using jQuery, and if there is no validation errors there, then I need to call the button click event. But I dunno how to do this.

can anyone give me some better idea, or how to check if there any validation error in a particular tab? thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the [ValidationSummary control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.aspx)?

Comment: Yup, If I display a message to tell them to check for 2nd tab it will be better

Answer (score 1):

Why Don't you use different validation groups for each tab and have a nextbutton on tab 1.
The next button on tab one will be attached to "ValidationGroupForTab1" so it validates the tab before they can move off it. Then only tab 2 has the submit button.

or you could  do somehing like this when you press submit..

```
Validate("ValidationGroupForTab1") 
 Validate("ValidationGroupForTab2").
```

to determine if the info on both tabs is valid and have a validation summary for each tab about the tab area and check the Page.IsValid.

This is definitely not a specific answer but it may give you some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ValidationGroup` Property of `Required Field validator.`

set same `ValidationGroup` for Ist Tab, and set another one `ValidationGroup` for second tab.
when user click on `'Next' button` then only 1st tab validation will be call.